# Как ловить название inline клавиатуры в FSM ? aiogram 3.4 + sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, aiogram-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста. Пишу бота на aiogram 3 + sqlalchemy. Нужно, чтобы при нажатие на inline клавишу, бот ловил название этой клавиши и добавлял ее в state

С reply клавиатурой разобрался, но как такой же код реализовать с inlin?

```
############################# FSM для дабавления/изменения данных #########################

class AddDetail(StatesGroup):
    category = State()
    name = State()
    number = State()
    status = State()

    detail_for_change = None

    texts = {
        "AddProduct:category": "Выберите изделия  заново ",
        "AddDetail:name": "Введите имя заново:",
        "AddDetail:number": "Введите заводской номер заново:",
        "AddDetail:status": "Введите статус заново:",
    }

##### Становимся в состояние ожидания ввода name для функции добавления данных #####
@admin_router.message(StateFilter(None), F.text == "Добавить данные по детали")
async def add_detail(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(
        "Выберите деталь", reply_markup=CO2010_KB
    )
    await state.set_state(AddDetail.name)
   
############################# Ловим состояние name и переходим в ожидание состояния number #########################
@admin_router.message(AddDetail.name, F.text)
async def add_number(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text == "." and AddDetail.detail_for_change:
        await state.update_data(name=AddDetail.detail_for_change.name)
    else:

        await state.update_data(name=message.text)
    await message.answer('Введите заводской номер')
    await state.set_state(AddDetail.number)
```

Comment: Практически никогда не нужно брать название самой кнопки в inline клавиатуре, всегда хватает её callback_data, задумайтесь над тем, что вы делаете, ну либо опишите детальнее задачу

Comment: Я делаю бота для производства, в которого будут добавлять:
Деталь: Плата кодирования и управления
Заводской номер: 12345
Статус данной детали: Настройка

Если делать это все на реплай клавиатуре, то это будет все очень громоздко, так как в некоторые изделия входят по 12+ деталей

Comment: Здорово. А что мешает сделать на inline? Полагаю, у вас будет база данных, положите в неё ваши детали с PK id и в callback_data кладите этот id и по нему доставайте из БД, в крайнем случае - словарик.